# Make script execute code before page is interpreted after website data is downloaded (JS)

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible for a browser extension/script to execute code **after** an element is downloaded but **before** it is interpreted?

I am aware that I can make a script execute at the beginning of a document (before anything else can happen), but I want to run a script that checks each element **before the browser interprets it** and deletes if it it's a script tag. If I waited until all the code was interpreted, the scripts in the HTML would've run.

I don't need pure JavaScript - importing libraries are allowed, although I would prefer pure JavaScript over jQuery.